# Which is more accepted: "hoi polloi", or "the hoi polloi"?

Tags: definite-articles, greek

I've seen that both 'hoi polloi' and 'the hoi polloi' can be used. Does anyone know which is more accepted or correct? Or are they the same?

Comment: It will depend on the context in which it is used. If you are wanting to use the expression, please provide a sample sentence in which you intend to use it.

Comment: Only hoi polloi use *the hoi polloi*.

Comment: The hoi polloi gathered at the Rio Grande River for a rendezvous get-together.

Comment: (The) alcove had a vaulted ceiling. (The) lacrosse goal had traditional netting. It seems once a phrase from another language gets accepted as English, we have no quarrel with doubling up on the thes.

Comment: @SvenYargs On the same tour was their visit to the La Brea Tarpits, Lake Malawi, and the La Alhambra

Comment: Most style guides for English just specify 'the hoi polloi'; not many people speak Ancient Greek nowadays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In its definition of *[hoi polloi](http://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/unabridged/hoi%20polloi)*, M-W Unabridged notes:

> Since *hoi polloi* is a transliteration of the Greek for “the many,”
>   some critics have asserted that the phrase should not be preceded by
>   the. They find “the hoi polloi” to be redundant, equivalent to “the
>   the many”—an opinion that fails to recognize that *hoi* means nothing
>   at all in English. Nonetheless, the opinion has influenced the
>   omission of *the* in the usage of some writers.
>
> But most writers use *the*, which is normal English grammar.

In its example usage sentences, M-W Unabridged gives examples of both usages:

> "strain so hard in making their questions comprehensible to *hoi
>   polloi*" — S. L. Payne
>
> "burlesque performance … for the *hoi polloi*" — Henry Miller

Comment: And there's also the never to be forgotten "As we staggered into land with all the waiters eating sand// wiches and tried to mooch a towel from the hoi polloi", John Sebastian in "Jug Band Music"

Comment: I suppose the fact that "hoi" means nothing in English allows the use of 'the'. Thanks, Gnawme.

Answer (score -2):

From [this](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/183475.html) article it seems like an article (the) is necessary because it translates directly to 'the many'

Comment: I don't think that article says that. It says that the definite article *the* duplicates *hoi,* but many people use it anyway. Also: if the article changes its URL your answer is rendered useless: please quote the relevant part of it in your answer, [referencing it](/help/how-to-reference) as required.

Answer (score -2):

I have been lectured by Brits that "the" should never be used, so English vs. American usage may be the crux of this question.

Comment: I'm afraid that is complete nonsense.