# Antonyms of "intelligentsia"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What words could be used as antonyms of *intelligentsia*?

The author of the book I am editing chose to use the word "unintelligentsia" in order to emphasise the (assumed) unintelligent or uncultured nature of the lower classes. I am seeking alternative antonyms.

The sentence in question, in reference to a popular TV show involving legal cases:

> He wisely decided that watching the {unintelligentsia} being scolded by a cranky old lady was the better choice.

The author's explanation of why he chose to use *unintelligentsia*:

> My use of the word unintelligentsia was meant to be playful. In the same way that Intelligentsia isn’t a pejorative, per se, but is often used as one, Unintelligentsia can be used and argued that it’s a neutral word. Although no one will believe you.

*Proletariat* might be suitable if you take the word literally, but when you’re using the word as a subtle insult, then you need a different antonym. Pleb is closer, but it’s definitely derogatory and doesn’t carry any sense of the group having their own culture.

So, in summary, I was looking for a word that isn’t overtly derogatory, and that describes a class of people that have (1) a shallow culture, and (2) a sense that being uneducated makes them, in some way, superior to well-educated people.

Example sentence:

> I wouldn't want to socialise with anyone from the *{antonym of intelligentsia}*; they're too unintelligent and uncultured for me

Comment: Request for clarification:  By the  unintelligentsia, do you mean the uncultured of all economic classes, or do you mean only the uncultured of the lower economic classes?  There are many uncultured people who are not members of the proletariat or the masses.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are two points that need clarification -- see my comment and the comment of  sumelic.  When these comments are addressed, I will vote to reopen.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are looking for? Is this with respect to theoretical Marxism, or is it for a particular society (eg current European, ancient Sparta), or what? And by 'opposite' do you mean literally opposed in adversarial life situations (like two people running for office), or do you mean all those people who are _not_ the intellectual elite (which would include the middle people who are neither here nor there), or do you mean only those who are all the way on the other side with contrary aspects?

Comment: Presumably, the author that used the word 'unintelligentsia' wasn't talking about the lower classes (the lower socio-economic classes) or the complement of those elite thought leaders (academics, think-tanks, goverment researchers) which would mean absolutely everybody else, but  rather the author intended a small group, those who are actively anti-intellectual, those who actively engage in specious, data-poor arguments. Or maybe the uninformed masses? Who knows? Actually, you do because you're reading that author. Can you tell us with more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***"idiocracy"***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiocracy) is the term coined by cult director Mike Judge (Beavis and Butthead, Office Space) in his 2006 film of that name. [Wikipedia described it as:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiocracy)

> *a dystopian society where anti-intellectualism and commercialism have run rampant, and which is devoid of intellectual curiosity, social responsibility, and coherent notions of justice and human rights*

Comment: @sumelic: But the question title asks "The opposite of “intelligentsia”, not "Has anyone come across this word "unintelligentsia" as the opposite of intelligentsia?"; which I interpreted as subordinate to the question, and the OP's suggested answer. Please edit the title as you see fit.

Comment: @sumelic: The question title does articulate a question. If the OP was unclear and asked a different (and incompatible) question in the details (as happens on SO/SE), take it up with them, not me; or edit it yourself.

Comment: @sumelic: That's incorrect. Question marks are routinely omitted on SO, and here are examples [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461409/difference-between-past-continuous-past-continuous-and-past-continuous-pa), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461400/both-for-more-than-two-objects), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461388/the-inability-to-ignore-danger). Certainly "The opposite of “intelligentsia”?" would be a question.

Comment: Yes, that is how I interpreted the question, as well.  It's asking for the opposite of "intelligentsia."  It in the details below poses "unintelligentsia" as a possibility, a possibility that the asker is uncertain of, even, but the question itself is asking for antonyms.

Comment: By the way, maybe "idiocrats" instead.  If "idiocracy" stands for an ideology, like "democracy" or "autocracy," while "intelligentsia" doesn't but instead stands for a group of people, then I'd say you'd have to use a form of the word "idiocracy" that doesn't denote an ideology but rather denotes its adherents, i.e., "idiocrats."

Comment: TBC and to visitors who may not know "its" history. The question *was* quite ambiguous at the beginning, it was possible to interpret it two different ways.  The OP greatly clarified his request while the question was placed on hold.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, Karl Marx has.  He called the opposite of the "intelligentsia," or "literati," the "proletariat."  The adjective is "proletarian."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proletariat

The proletariat is often at odds with the intelligentsia in a battle over being right or being strong, the latter being attributed to the proletariat.  The proletariat position is that at the end of the day, survival depends on being strong, not being right.  Moreover, the proletariat become very oppositional to education and the educated classes and suggest that being "right" is established through argument, and because the educated are educated at winning arguments and because people can and very often do win arguments without actually being right based solely on that learned skill, being "right" isn't all it's trumped up to be.  Essentially, the proletariat position is that their rights are being trampled simply because they are being out-argued by the educated classes that are skilled at arguing.

Anyway, the opposite of the intelligentsia is the proletariat.  Here's an example of the two terms being used in juxtaposition:

> The members of the Tsarist-era intelligentsia who remained in Bolshevik Russia (the USSR) were proletarianized ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligentsia)).

Comment: Also [the masses](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/masses) or even [plebs](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pleb?q=plebs) Note _plebs_ is derogatory

Comment: Marx meant political opposition as much as conceptual antithesis but this is still bang on.  Not least because I can't think of any alternative that isn't derogatory.

Comment: I don't believe that is entirely accurate. From [Wikipaedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligentsia#Bolshevik_perspective): *In Russia, the Bolsheviks did not consider the status class of the intelligentsiya to be a true social class, as defined in Marxist philosophy. In that time, the Bolsheviks used the Russian word prosloyka (stratum) to identify and define the intelligentsia as a separating layer without an inherent class character.* ...

Comment: ... *In the creation of post-monarchic Russia, Lenin was firmly critical of the class character of the intelligentsia, commending the growth of "the intellectual forces of the workers and the peasants" and asserting that the "**bourgeoisie** and their accomplices", regardless of the depth of their education, were "lackeys of capital".* It is rather the bourgeoisie and capitalists who were the opposite of the proletariat.

Comment: How **Proletariat** can be possible antonym for intelligentsia. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proletariat) and other dictionaries defines it as: the laboring class or the lowest social or economic class of a community. I am surprised.

Comment: The question has been edited. @ianapps left a clarifying comment as an answer: 'The word I'm exploring is "unintelligentsia", used by the author of a book that I am editing. I'm not sure that "proletariat" has the equivalent meaning. Unless I am mistaken, it simply refers to the lower classes per se rather than describing the (assumed) character of the lower classes.'

Comment: You are making a logical fallacy. Even if proletariat is opposed to intelligentsia, this doesn't mean that all uncultured classes are proletariat. Uneducated traders, business owners and even priests would never fall into this category.

Comment: _Proletariat_ in the proper Marxist sense doesn't even imply that it is a **lower** class. (Indeed, given the entire thrust of Marxism, how could it?) Rather, the proletariat is strictly defined by its relationship to the societal mode of production. Also, as a member of the intelligentsia himself (albeit a rather beggarly one),  Marx could hardly see the intelligentsia as necessarily opposed to the proletariat, or vice versa.

Moreover, none of the several positions attributed in this answer to the proletariat (meaning 'Marxists'?) are in any way accurate - and that's putting it kindly.

Comment: The comments here are being very diplomatic. To be clear, this is wrong - the proletariat is not the 'opposite' (whatever its many meanings are) of the intelligentsia. The intelligentsia class is a cross-cutting social class, where the others are economic classes. In Marxist theory, the intelligentsia are thought leaders that can help drive changes among the economic classes (eg helping the bourgeoisie in the French Revolution, and the proletariat in the Russian). The intelligentsia usually have few members in the proletariat, since education is usually an expensive thing.

Comment: @Mitch: But maybe the _dumbenproletariat_ would work?

Comment: In the writings of Marx, he specifically states that the proletariat opposes the intelligentsia.  You are devolving into semantics, but back when Marx wrote that,  since then, and even today in the United States with the rise of Trumpism, we see the proletariat oppose the intelligentsia.  You are losing sight of the reality that the proletariat does and always has opposed the intelligentsia, often with considerable violence.  So by definition, that opposition makes it opposite.

Comment: I thought the previous edit was rather good, especially the paragraph breaks?

Comment: @Billy: Semantics are literally what this question is about. Also, where in the writings of Marx does he specifically state that the proletariat opposes the intelligentsia? It might be worth your while checking your sources and revising your answer to take account of the generally accepted definition of "proletariat" and the conventional understanding of class in Marxism.

Answer (score 9):

Other potential words are

**hoi polloi**  (PLURAL NOUN) [**<sub>Oxford Dictionaries</sub>**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hoi_polloi)

:derogatory

> The masses; the common people.
>
> > "avoid mixing with the hoi polloi."

*the* **Multitude**   [**<sub>Oxford Dictionaries</sub>**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/multitude)

> The mass of ordinary people without power or influence.
>
> > "placing ultimate political power in the hands of the multitude."

Comment: Also, using "the hoi polloi" is technically redundant. "hoi" means "the" and "polloi" means "many".

Comment: @peaceoutside: See [Which is more accepted: “hoi polloi”, or “the hoi polloi”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/366496/which-is-more-accepted-hoi-polloi-or-the-hoi-polloi)

Comment: @peaceoutside We're using it in English, however, so like any loanword, it will acquire English conventions as it becomes assimilated. The *Milky Way Galaxy* is also *technically* redundant, as is the *Sahara Desert*, *Timor Leste*, and famously, *the La Brea Tar Pits*.

Comment: @peaceoutside see 'the La Alhambra'

Comment: Please don't just nominate words and then link to copied text. You still have to write your own answer, in your words, with an explanation of why you think this is a suitable answer to the request. We're trying to build up a library of expert answers for future visitors, and that requires original content.

Comment: @tchrist Never updated my answer after original question was posted. The  title/header was asking direct opposite/antonym of intelligentsia: ***The opposite of "intelligentsia"***. Both of the suggested words are self explanatory. I'll  try next time.

Comment: @HotLicks all these description or "basket of deplorables" as you call it was added later. Also, there was no direct connotation of Karl Marx usage of the word "Proletariat" as antonym to "Intelligentsia". So, it wasn't much clear at that time.

Answer (score 7):

The [***"illiterati"***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/illiterati):

> People who are not well educated or well informed about a particular subject or sphere of activity.

or the ***"uneducated"*** would probably fit what you mean. If you wanted to be Marxian about it, I guess it's possible to use [***"lumpenproletariat"***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumpenproletariat) (*lumpenproles* for short). The usage of *"proletariat"* by itself as suggested [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/461345/313443) is something of a stretch...

Answer (score 3):

**[ignorati](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ignorati)**

> (slang, derogatory) The wilfully ignorant; those who choose to ignore inconvenient facts or make public claims based on falsehoods. blend of ignorant +‎ literati

This term captures well the idea of "people that have (1) a shallow culture, and (2) a sense that being uneducated makes them, in some way, superior to well-educated people" i.e. ignorant and proud of it. A Google search shows how it has been counterposed with *intelligentsia*:

[Ignorati are becoming the new intellectual elite](http://omnipotentpoobah.com/2010/10/15/the-ignoratti-are-becoming-the-new-ruling-elite/)

> This nation is well on its way to becoming an anti-intellectual wasteland ruled by the **ignorati instead of the intelligentsia** or the commonsentsia. We’ve produced a crop of “leaders” without the good sense to come in out of the rain. The Christine O’Donnells, Sarah Palins, Sharron Angles, and Michele Bachmanns of the world recoil at the mention of anything requiring more thought than their many bubbleheaded Tweets.

[NY Times And Washington Post All But Abandon Specialized Climate Science Coverage](https://thinkprogress.org/in-epic-blunder-ny-times-and-washington-post-all-but-abandon-specialized-climate-science-coverage-96355834aef2/)

> OK, I added the final sentence, but still this move is doubly head-exploding in a post-Sandy world where even the media elite now know they aren’t free from the ravages of climate change. And again, we’ve only seen the impact of slightly more than a degree Fahrenheit of warming — we’re all but certain to see at least 5 times as much warming this century as we did last century, especially if the **ignorati (not-so-intelligentsia?)** gag themselves on the greatest story never told.

Answer (score 2):

**unintelligentsia**

The OED does not list usage of **unintelligentsia**, but does for (the) **unintelligent.**

BUT, a search of Google Books shows a number of usages.

Here is just one of such:

> Shaw contested, in the 1890s
>
> > ... that numerous body that may be called the **Unintelligentsia** was
> >     as unconscious of Ibsen as of any other political influence:

(*[Ibsen and the Irish Revival](https://books.google.com/books?id=UtKGDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA75&dq=%22unintelligentsia%22&pg=PA75#v=onepage&q=%22unintelligentsia%22&f=false),* by  Irina Ruppo Malone, p. 75)

Especially in literary use, I see no reason not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

**rabble** might fit.

> **(the rabble)** Ordinary people, especially when regarded as socially
>   inferior or uncouth.
>
> > the British feel no compunction about ushering
> >     the gentry into the coach and packing the rabble off to debtor's
> >     prison

Comment: Please don't just nominate words and then link to copied text. You still have to write your own answer, in your words, with an explanation of why you think this is a suitable answer to the request. We're trying to build up a library of expert answers for future visitors, and that requires original content not just dictionary spam.

Answer (score 1):

**[Lowbrow](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lowbrow)**:

> of, relating to, or suitable for a person with little taste or intellectual interest · a *lowbrow* horror movie
>
> —**lowbrow** *noun*

(Merriam-Webster)

Comment: Please don't just nominate words and then link to copied text. You still have to write your own answer, in your words, with an explanation of why you think this is a suitable answer to the request. We're trying to build up a library of expert answers for future visitors, and that requires original content not just dictionary spam.

Answer (score 0):

> The OP is looking for **a word that isn’t overtly derogatory**, and that
>   describes a class of people that have (1) a shallow culture, and (2) a
>   sense that being uneducated makes them, in some way, superior to
>   well-educated people. (Emphasis added)

The requirement that the word not be overtly derogatory rules out a lot of candidate words and phrases. To mention a few:

> The Great Unwashed
>
> Know-Nothings
>
> booboisie
>
> Several words in other answers, but I won't point a finger

My candidate is a phrase: ***the common man***.  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/common%20man) says:

> the undistinguished commoner lacking class or rank distinction or
>   special attributes

This is in fact a snobbish phrase, although more subtle than the ones above.   Any word you use for the unintelligentsia  will be snobbish; the word intelligentsia is itself snobbish.  William Buckley is reported to have said, about intellectuals and government:

> I would rather be governed by the first 2,000 people in the telephone
>   directory than by the Harvard University faculty.

[Source](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/10/31/telegovern/)

Of course, Buckley graduated from Yale, so he was biased.

The reason why *the common man* is suitable for the OP's purposes is that the intelligentsia go to so much effort to distinguish themselves from ordinary people and take so much pride in being extraordinary.  And, of course, all the juicy words and phrases are ruled out because they are overtly derogatory.

As for the single word:  not everything in the multiverse can be described by a single word, and this, I suspect, is one of them.