# "Both" for more than two objects

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, lists

If I were to ask:

> Which children did you bring?

and you respond:

> I brought both Adam and Billy.

The "both" implies not only that you brought two children, but that you brought your *only* two children (that the whole set was brought).

If, however, you had more than two children, neither:

> I brought Adam, Billy, and Charlotte.

nor:

> I brought all of Adam, Billy, and Charlotte.

would have the same connotation that you brought *all your children*.  The first gives no idea how many children there are total, and the second sounds more like you brought "all of" each individual item.  Is there a word that has extends the meaning of "both" to more than two?

Comment: Hello and welcome, donnyton. I would like to ask a clarifying question: In what real-world context does *I brought both Adam and Billy* necessarily  imply that the speaker has only these 2 children?

Comment: I agree with what @Knotell is suggesting.  Saying "both" in that sentence can imply that Adam and Billy are your only children but not necessarily.  It would depend on context.

Comment: I have a son and two daughters: Adam, Charlotte, and Dot. We had planned to go to the zoo yesterday. Charlotte and Dot weren't feeling well, so Adam asked if his best friend is Billy could come instead. **I brought both Adam and Billy.** _The word "both" does not imply that I have two kids._

Answer (score 1):

I can think of no single word in the sense you mean, but I believe a slight rephrasing of your last sentence would serve the purpose:

> I brought them all: Adam, Billy, and Charlotte.

Comment: Simple and to the point. I don't get some of these questions....It ain't just children either.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "[all of](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/all-of)" in the sentence listing three children wouldn't parallel the meaning "both" has in the sentence listing two children but would tend to intimate that Adam, Billy, and Charlotte constitute a paltry amount of children to bring.

There is no word that can be used exactly like "both" but for more than two.  You would instead have to say something like:

> I brought Adam, Bill, and Charlotte, all three.